# define_method not returning any results

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a lot of methods that do exactly the same, but they need to be defined each with a specific name. So I tried the following from within the method that calls each individual `format_` method:

```
['street', 'postcode', 'email', 'type', 'subtype', 'dsc', 'duration'].each do |attribute|
  define_method("self.format_#{attribute}") do |value|
    return cleanup(value)
  end
end
```

Before, I had a separate method for each element in the array as such:

```
def self.format_street value
  return cleanup(value)
end
```

How can I get the first block to generate methods for each element in the array?

---

Here the new implementation based on the answer from Andrew Marshall:

```
def self.analyze_input! formatted_information, category

  analyzed_information = {}
  attributes = eval(category).attributes

  ['inst_number', 'name', 'head_of_department', 'street', 'city', 'phone', 'classification', 'sub_classification'].each do |attribute|
     define_singleton_method(:"analyze_#{attribute}") do |value|
       value
     end
   end

   formatted_information.each do |key, value|
     if attributes.include?(key)
       analyzed_information[:"#{key}"] = send("analyze_#{key}", value)
     end
   end

 end
```

Comment: Do you really want to be (re)defining these methods on every call to `analyze_input!`.  Why not define all those `analyze_<attribute>` methods outside of this method using either approach suggested below?

Comment: No, I dont want to do that. The error is the same though unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting `self.` in the name of the method being defined doesn’t have the effect you want, it literally creates a method with exactly that name:

```
define_method(:'self.foo') { 'bar' }
self.foo  # undefined method
send('self.foo')  #=> "bar"
```

Instead omit the `self.` and instead use [`define_singleton_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method):

```
attributes = %w[street postcode email type subtype dsc duration]
attributes.each do |attribute|
  define_singleton_method(:"format_#{attribute}") do |value|
    cleanup(value)
  end
end
```

You must also omit the explicit `return` in your block, as it will return from the *method*, not the block. The implicit return is enough.

Comment: I implemented those changes but get now: ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block

Comment: I'll update the original question so you can see the implementation.

Comment: @Severin I believe my updated answer should fix that issue, which was with your use of `return` within a block within a method. (Though I can’t replicate your error—what Ruby version are you using?)

Comment: I am using 2.0.0-p353. Unfortunately even omitting the return doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
class << self
  ['street', 'postcode', 'email', 'type', 'subtype', 'dsc', 'duration'].each do |attribute|
    define_method("format_#{attribute}") do |value|
      cleanup(value)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Still got the same problem. Tried placing the block within the method that calls the one that should get generated and as the first one in the document. Were would you place this block?

Comment: Within your class, `class Foo; class << self; ...`

Comment: That throws this error: ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block

Comment: Did you double check yourvsyntax? Code is ok there

Answer (score 1):

Since the methods are all identical, creating aliases with [`Module#alias_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-alias_method) or using [`BasicObject#method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) would be the most direct approach.

**Using alias_method**

```
NAMES= ['street', 'postcode', 'email', 'type', 'subtype', 'dsc', 'duration']

class Clean
  class << self
    def cleanup(value)
      puts "cleanup #{value}"
    end

    NAMES.each {|n| alias_method "format_#{n}", :cleanup}

    def doit
      format_street(5)
      format_type(13)
    end
  end   
end

Clean.methods(false) # =>[:cleanup, :doit, :format_street, :format_postcode, \
                     # => :format_email, :format_type, :format_subtype, \
                     # => :format_dsc, :format_duration]
Clean.doit
  # => cleanup 5
  # => cleanup 13
Clean.format_dsc(3)  # => cleanup 3
```

**Using method_missing**

```
class Clean
  class << self
    @names = NAMES.map {|e| "format_#{e}".to_sym}

    def cleanup(value)
     puts "cleanup #{value}"
    end

    def method_missing(name, *args)
      if @names.include? name
        cleanup args.first
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def doit
      format_street(5)
      format_type(13)
    end
  end   
end

Clean.doit
  # => cleanup 5
  # => cleanup 13
Clean.format_email(7) # => cleanup 7
Clean.cat(9)   # NoMethodError: undefined method `cat' for Clean:Class
```